# GCP Cloud Logging take so much cost, and how to disable it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging

[image: GCP Billing Cloud Logging metric]

Hello, I want to ask why service Cloud Logging take so much cost, and how Cloud Logging works? I want to disable with refere this link https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/disabling-cloud-logging but I got error.

[image: Error disable cloud logging gcp]

Comment: Did you read the error and then select a project and try again?

Comment: Note: Google Cloud services do not generate 910 GB of storage. That means your applications are generating that log volume. Analyze your applications and log what is required. I also do not recommend disabling logging - just reduce what you are logging.

Comment: Hello @Mas Dimas. Does the given answer helped? Your issue got resolved or are you still facing it?

Answer (score 5):

You can either use Organisation Policy to set a global policy, at organisation level, to deactivate Cloud Logging.

At project level, you can't do that, but you can change/deactivate Cloud Logging. For that, go to Cloud Logging Router, and change, or disable the `_Default` route. For instance, exclude the most noisy logs and keep the others.

[image]

Comment: you can disable the _Defaut sink (but it cannot be deleted)